# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil when the dateString is @"19900415"

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

`NSDateFormatter dateFromString` returns `nil` when the `dateString` is `@"19900415"`.

If `dateString` is another value, it will return the correct value.

Format is `@"yyyyMMdd"`.

Here is the code:

```
- (NSDate *)dateWithString:(NSString *)dateString format:(NSString *)format {
  if (!dateString || !format) {
    return nil;
  }

  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:format];
  return [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Comment: Your code worked, try to debug input props, maybe it's nil.

Comment: Input is correct. I have tried to input @"19900416" and @"19900414", return correctly. Only @"19900415" return nil

Comment: Try setting locale like: `formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];`

Comment: @nayem That's the default so that won't change anything.

Comment: @foobin What is the output of `NSLog(@"Locale: %@", [NSLocale currentLocale]);`

Comment: Are you living in China? In China on 1990 April 15 daylight saving time has changed where 00:00:00-00:59:59 has been skipped.

Comment: Add a reliable time representation for example `12:00` or change the locale.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine I've added harcoded values and its working fine the problem here is your inputs are wrong or maybe due to Locale? use break point and try to debug where you're getting the wrong values i've added some extra checks to prevent further error :-

Final method will look like this:-

```
-(NSDate *)dateWithString:(NSString *)dateString format:(NSString *)format {

    BOOL isNil=(!dateString || !format);
    BOOL isEmpty=(!dateString.length || !format.length);
    BOOL isMismatch=(format.length!=dateString.length);

    if (isNil || isEmpty || isMismatch ) {
        NSLog(@"Please check input values");
        return nil;
    }
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:format];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDate *date=[formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"DATE IS : %@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);
    return date;

}
```